# Finding convergence of a series of real exponentiated numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I think my teacher should haev written series instead of sequence?

In any case, first off: I just proved that {$x_n$} = $q^n$ converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ for $0<q<1$. So, I at least know that when we have such a q, that my final term $q^n$ in this series goes to zero, and then $q^{n+1}$ . . .

Can I make a sort of induction argument here?

Comment: also, I was thinking originally that this would converge (trivially?) for q = 0, but that's not true because $0^0$ is not defined is it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have (for $q\ne 0$)
$$1+q+q^2+\cdots +q^n=\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}.$$

Comment: is this a formmula that I did not know about, or did you just derive that in your head?

Comment: Multiply $1+q+q^2+\cdots +q^{n}$ by $1-q$. There will be lots of cancellation. The formula is a special case of the formula for the sum of a finite geometric sequence. Odds are good that you have seen a version of it before. Perhaps as $a+ar+\cdots+ar^n=\frac{a-ar^{n+1}}{1-r}$.

Comment: well, that makes this easy then. as before $q^{n+1}$ will go to zero  for $0<q<1$ so this series goes to $\frac{1}{1-q}$

Comment: That's right. Except that the answer is $-1\lt q\lt 1$. If $q$ has absolute value less than $1$, then $q^{n+1}$ has limit $0$.  You also need to argue that the sum does not exist if $|q|\ge 1$. For that, one looks at the original series.

Comment: hm, why didn't that hold for a sequence (the problem we did yesterday) but it holds for a series?

Comment: What is "that"?  And your teacher did write down a sequence, it is the sequence of partial sums of the series $1+q+q^2+\cdots$.

Comment: hah, sorry for my stupid language.

For {$x_n$} = $q^n$ we just have convergence for $0<q<1$, not for $-1<q<1$, but as a series this same term has the -1 lower bound.

edit: thank you for the clarification, I didn't realize that could be classified as a sequence.

Comment: For $q^n$, we do have convergence to $0$ for $-1\lt q\lt 1$. If I recall correctly, the question only **asked** for $0\lt q\lt 1$.

Comment: ah, okay, that makes more sense, I am not sure why the question asked for that though. also, the argument for where the sequence does not converge is simple as well: let $|q| \geq 1$, then $q^{n+1}$ has no limit as n goes to infinity and thus the sequence can not converge.

Comment: also: do we have to throw out the case of q = 0? 

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0^0

the first term is meaningless

Comment: If $q=0$, we are looking at the series $1+0+0+0+\cdots$. Perfectly respectable. In taking limits, "$0^0$" is an indeterminate form. In summation notation, $0^0$ is interpreted as $1$. There have been questions about this on MSE, with much lengthier answers that say the same thing.